# Author list limited to first 100 when assigning to entry?

Tags: users, control-panel, author

We have more than 100 authors in a user group, but when selecting an author for an entry, only the first 100 are listed in the (a-z) dropdown. Whats the best way to display them all (or up the parameter?)

Comment: Hey Simon, if you’re referring to the Author setting in the Edit Entry page of the Control Panel, then this sounds like a bug. FFR please send issues with the Control Panel over to P&T directly, either by sending an email to support@buildwithcraft.com, or using the “Send a message to Craft support” widget on your dashboard.

Comment: Ups, totally missed that you meant the control-panel...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Craft sets the limit of the [ElementCriteriaModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel) to 100.

If you want to get all/more entries just set the `.limit` parameter to `null` or a number:

```twig
{% set allUsers = craft.users.limit(null).find() %}
```

```twig
{% set someUsers = craft.users.limit(200).find() %}
```

A list of all available parameters can be found here: [`craft.users`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.users)

Comment: Found this rentetly when trying to build a sitemap. the null is a nice tip there. Thanks!